# Multer while getting error " transfer-encoding' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, express

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
        <title>Node file uploads</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="container">
        <h1>File upload</h1>
        <%= typeof msg!= 'undefined' ? msg: ''%>
        <form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="file-field input-field">
                <div class="btn grey">
                    <span>File</span>
                    <input name="myImage" type="file">
                </div>
                <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                    <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
        </form>   
        </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**NODEJS CODE**

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const ejs =  require('ejs');
const path=  require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app =  express();

// middle ware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//set storage engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
     destination: './public/uploads/',
     filename:(res,file,cb)=>{
            cb(null,file.fieldname+'-'+Date.now()+path.extname(file.originalname));
     }
});

// init app
const upload = multer({storage:storage}).single('myImage');
const port  = 3000;
// ejs
app.set('view engine','ejs');
//public folder
app.use(express.static('./public'));
// routing
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.render('index');
}); 
app.post('/upload',(req,res)=>{
   upload(res,res,(err)=>{
        if(err){
            res.render('index',{msg:err});
            res.send('error uploading');
        }else{
            // console.log(req.file);
            res.send('test');
        }
   });
});
app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log('server is connected at '+ port);
});
```

**Error**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'transfer-encoding' of undefined
>       at hasbody (/var/www/html/nodeuploads/node_modules/type-is/index.js:93:21)
>       at typeofrequest (/var/www/html/nodeuploads/node_modules/type-is/index.js:127:8)
>       at multerMiddleware (/var/www/html/nodeuploads/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:18:10)
>       at app.post (/var/www/html/nodeuploads/app.js:40:4)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/nodeuploads/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (/var/www/html/nodeuploads/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (/var/www/html/nodeuploads/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/nodeuploads/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at /var/www/html/nodeuploads/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (/var/www/html/nodeuploads/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)

When i click submit button below message is displayed

> transfer-encoding' of undefined

Please let me know if additional details are required for debugging this issue

Thanks

Comment: upload(res,res,(err)=>{ -----> you are passing res,res . You are passing response object in the first argument. But , you have to pass request object as the first argument, modify the code and test the application.

Comment: thank you dude i made mistake